# Java. Подскажите пожалуйста оператор чтобы сравнить строки по значению противовположный equals()

Tags: java

> else if (select != ("1" | "2" | "3"))

select, "1",  "2" и "3" имеют тип String, поэтому != не подходит

Comment: противоположный equals (), смею предположить:  !equals ()

Comment: спасибо, однако такого не существует

Comment: я про:  !строка.equals (строка)

Comment: в девятке - `!Set.of( "1", "2", "3" ).contains( select )`. В более ранних версиях вместо `Set.of` можно использовать `Arrays.asList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else if (!select.equals("1")||!select.equals("2")||!select.equals("3"))
```

Comment: Это выражение будет всегда возвращать true при любых select != null

Answer (score 2):

Строки кроме значений "1", "2" или "3" могут также иметь и значение `null`. И если окажется так, что строка `select` равна `null`, то при проверке предложенной @Tsyklop вы получите NullPointerException. Правильно проверять так:
    `if(!"1".equals(select)&&!"2".equals(select)&&!"3".equals(select))`

т.е. при любом значении `select` отличном от "1", "2" и "3" будет `true`.